# How to restore taxonomy terms and node relationships?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, database

I was using the [Delete Orphaned Terms](https://www.drupal.org/project/delete_orphaned_terms) module to delete unused terms. Today, bad things happened: it deleted lots of taxonomy terms although they're are not orphaned. Then I found [a serious issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1361332) about this.

I have a backup of my whole system. Now, I want to restore only these taxonomy terms (25 terms) and the **node relationships**. How can I do that? Is it possible to make it via phpMyAdmin etc?